# Activity Still Runs - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have created a BootReceiver which creates a new activity and popup an Alert Dialog. 
After pressing OK/Cancel that activity still is not closed completely. I can see the same in Window List button & I can see the Alert dialog from the Window list.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

My code looks like below , calling finish after OK/Cancel buttoon protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams;

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    // Windows Attributes   
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    winParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    winParams.flags |= (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    getWindow().setAttributes(winParams);

     // Show Popup
    popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setPositiveButton("agree", new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                if( DEBUG ) Log.d(LOG_TAG, " AGREE CLICKED"  );

        finish();}})

    .setNegativeButton("disagree", new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                if( DEBUG ) Log.d(LOG_TAG, " DISAGREE CLICKED"  );
    finish();}})

    .setOnCancelListener(
        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                finish();
    }});

    popup.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    popup.setTitle("title");
    popup.setMessage("Message");

    dialog = popup.create();

    winParams =  dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    winParams.flags |= (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(winParams);

    dialog.setOnDismissListener(AlwaysReqWhenPS);
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(this);             
    dialog.show();

}


protected void onStop() {
    if( DEBUG ) Log.d(LOG_TAG, " OnStop Called"  );
    super.onStop();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if( DEBUG ) Log.d(LOG_TAG, " onDestroy Called"  );
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onPause() {
    if( DEBUG ) Log.d(LOG_TAG, " onPause Called"  );
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Window list button.? How are the ok/cancel buttons in the alert dialog manipulating the activity?

Comment: You shouldn't start activities on boot. It's frustrating and slows the boot process significantly.

Comment: @Gopinath: Window list mean where we can see the list of previously opened activites may be button next to HOME button. added the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

If by "window list" you mean the faded dialog that pops up when you long-press the home button, then it is perfectly fine. That window doesn't necessarily show the currently running applications but rather the recently used ones.

In your dialog you can simply invoke `finish()` once you've done and you want to make it disappear. This is mainly all you can do..

Android will manage the "garbage collection" of the activities by itself. The important thing is that you correctly allocate and deallocate resources throughout the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), such as registering battery-consuming services in the `onResume(...)` event an unregistering them again in the `onPause(...)` event.

Comment: @Jury: Calling finish() after OK/CANCEL, added the code snippet